# CAS + SAML1.1 and clock drift

Tags: spring, spring-security, cas

I'm facing an error 401 when I do a request from my application to CAS Server. I saw that this meaning that the time between the servers are different. So I found this [link, showing how configure it.](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/Saml11TicketValidationFilter+Example)

I'm using spring-cas-client to do the connection between my app and CAS Server. In this example shows how to configure in the web.xml. There are a way to configure in my applicationContext-security.xml.

Tks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only for document, I found the error. And the simplest way to fix this error is synchronize servers with the same NTP Server.